# How to reconcile two separate knex migrations, and is there documentation for the knex_migrations table?

Tags: knex.js

The knex migration module uses a table with a schema that has a *migration time*, as well as a *batch* id, along with a file name associated with that migration step.

Im running knex migration from `branch A` of a codebase against a database which previously was migrated with `branch B`, using a different set of migration scripts (which are **not in collision** with `A`).

**Problem:**

When I try to run the migration for `B`, there is a file (i.e. 12345678_add_a_table.js) that is in the knex_migrations table which is *not* in the codebase for *A*.   Since I don't have this file, knex complains that it doesn't understand what the state of the *knex_migrations* table is, and it stops the migration.

However, this is unnecessary, as that file isn't needed at all.  So, **I need knex to keep going forward even though it isn't 100% sure where some of the migrations that happened in the knex_migrations table come from**.

I've thought of two ways to get knex to complete succesfully.

**Solutions:**

- run a `--force` option of some sort during migration, i cannot find such an option
- rebuild a migration table manually to trick knex into thinking everything is ok.

Is there a way to do the former?  I suppose the latter would work otherwise, but I'd prefer the former since its generic and easily automated.

Answer (score 0):

You should build up your db schema changes again from for example sql dump that has some DB version, which is in consistent state with migrations.

That works always and your migrated branch will be always consistent without any extra leftovers. It is as trivial to have script that resets DB to consistent state before applying migrations as it is to run knex command line client (I suppose you have npm script for that).

Also you should already have dumps of your development data laying around to recover DB if it gets broken (I actually usually just use e2e test data sets in development, so I never need to worry of this stuff at all... DB is always regenerated in startup).

There is no option called `--force`. I has not been implemented, because it has been considered harmful... Schema that you are using for development might get very different by accident unless you are resetting it to some verified state every now and then (for example if you did run migration that had bug).